# Command line flags that are needed in modules that are deep into the class tree

Tags: python, command-line

Imagine that we have a program with a command-line interface and we give it flags. These flags are used by classes that are deep in the class tree.

For example, the main program uses an instance of class A, class A uses an instance of class B, ... uses an instance of class Z. If Z needs the flag given in the main program, we would have to give this flag as an argument to the constructor of class A, class B, class C... all the way to class Z.

Of course, there are alternatives, such as using environment variables or having this variable defined in a file or even hard-coded in the main program. But are there more accurate alternatives?

Thanks in advance to whoever may read this.

I have used environment variables for now, which is not a great approach.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is as follows. Assume you have a module called `argutils.py` (you can put the code below in an existing utility module if you prefer):

```
# argutils.py
import argparse

options = None

def get_command_line_options():
    if options:
        return options
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...) # define as needed
    parser.add_argument(...) # add arguments as needed for your CLI
    global options
    options = parser.parse_args()
    return options
```

Then in the rest of your code you can do

```
from argutils import options as cmdline_options
# and then use attributes of the cmdline_options object as desired
```